# Iphone app crashes at line: UIKit`-[UINibDecoder validateAndIndexKeys:length:]

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uikit, uilabel

I have searched far and wide on this one and I'm not sure what is going on.  I added a new ViewController to my project and hooked up a `UILabel` to storyboard file and assigned it the new custom Class.  It is completely blank and doesn't do anything, but crashes on load at this line:

```
UIKit`-[UINibDecoder validateAndIndexKeys:length:]
```

I have another ViewController setup the exact same way and it works fine.  I must be missing something here.  I tried to Clean and Build and I even tried to rebuild completely including deleting and making a new `UIViewController` on the storyboard.  I have figured out that once I remove the `UILabel` from the code, it loads fine.  Here is my code:

```
@interface GoalDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *goalLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *goal;

@end

#import "GoalDetailViewController.h"

@implementation GoalDetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // nameLabel.text = name;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: try synthesizing `goalLabel` and did you add actual label in your view and connected it?